# Google Cloud Compute Engine OS Login permission denied issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-iam

When setting up the OS Login on one GCE instance I get a `Permission denied` message for a new user of the project.

As per the Google Cloud documentation on OS Login, I've set metadata to `enable-oslogin TRUE`, and the permission for the user in the instance to `roles/compute.osLogin`, as there's no further Organization or service account required in this test case. Firewall rules are OK too.

I've enabled the role `Project Editor` and it works, but I don't want the user to be an `Editor` nor a `Viewer`, just to SSH into the instance and manage it with Cloud IAM.

This is the error I'm seeing:

```
DEBUG: Executing command: [u'/usr/bin/ssh', u'-t', u'-i', u'/home/test/.ssh/google_compute_engine', u'-o', u'CheckHostIP=no', u'-o', u'HostKeyAlias=compute.xxxxx', u'-o', u'IdentitiesOnly=yes', u'-o', u'StrictHostKeyChecking=no', u'-o', u'UserKnownHostsFile=/home/test/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts', u'test_com@xx.xx.xx.xx']
Permission denied (publickey).
DEBUG: (gcloud.beta.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 981, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 807, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/compute/ssh.py", line 262, in Run
    return_code = cmd.Run(ssh_helper.env, force_connect=True)
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/util/ssh/ssh.py", line 1258, in Run
    raise CommandError(args[0], return_code=status)
CommandError: [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding below IAM roles solves it, so it requires the SA role as well, something not very clear from the Google Cloud documentation.

```
Compute OS Login
Role
Access to log in to a Compute Engine instance as a standard (non-administrator) user.

Service Account User
Role
Run operations as the service account.
```

Comment: It is documented in the article "Configuring OS Login roles on user accounts" If your VM instance uses a service account, you need the roles/iam.serviceAccountUser on the service account that is associated with the VM instance. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#configure_users

Comment: Yep, agreed, though the 'if' on the documentation and the concept on the default SA for managing GCE instances might not very clear at a first glance.

Answer (score 0):

You can grant the `roles/compute.osLogin` or `roles/compute.osAdminLogin` roles at the instance level by using the gcloud beta compute instances add-iam-policy-binding command

Please refer the [Google Docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access)

Comment: That's done already, though the issue looks like a limitation on OS Login, where it seems it requires some Editor permission.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is for a Gmail, Yahoo,etc, not with the organization syntax, it is considered as [external user](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#granting_os_login_iam_roles), so you need to set the permission roles/compute.osLoginExternalUser at organization level to the user.

It should work once it has the role for external user set.

Comment: I have only a test project with no Organization defined, and there's no option for it there.

Comment: The Editor role only includes these permissions for os login:

compute.instances.osAdminLogin
compute.instances.osLogin

So I would recommend to use roles/compute.osAdminLogin to see if it works, since it's the same permissions included on Editor.